# Create STD IN/OUT Buffer for a Program Running in a Screen Session

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, nohup, fifo

## Environment

```
Linux version 2.6
Screen version 4.03.01
```

I am running an application inside of a screen session. The program prints to STDOUT and reads from STDIN.

## What I would like to do:

First, have STDOUT of the `screen` `tee`'d to a file. For some reason, piping to tee only writes the first few lines, then stops. This maybe because the shell script I am executing runs other applications/shell scripts... Is there a way to connect to the STDOUT of the screen session?

Second, I would like to create a file, like a fifo maybe?, that I can write data do and have it send that data to the STDIN of the screen session.

I am open to other suggestions, such as not using `screen` at all and doing something with `nohup` and some `fifo`'s

Basically, I want to background an application and have a file that I can tail for the output and another to redirect input to.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I want to background an application and have a file that I can tail for the output and another to redirect input to.

If that is the case, then (1) we need to background `application` and send its output to file `file`:

```
application >file &
```

And, (2) we need to tail application's output to command `another`:

```
tail -f | another
```

#### Example

Let's create a sample `application` and `another`:

```
$ application() { while sleep 1; do date; done; }
$ another() { grep 2017; }
```

Now, let's start `application` in the background:

```
$ application >file &
[1] 5989
```

And, let's run `another` in the foreground:

```
$ tail -f file | another
Sat May 20 18:32:05 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:32:06 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:32:07 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:32:08 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:32:09 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:32:10 PDT 2017
[...clip...]
```

#### Inside a screen session using a FIFO

First, start a screen session.  Then run:

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ application >fifo &
[1] 8129
$ cat fifo | another
Sat May 20 18:50:39 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:50:40 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:50:41 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:50:42 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:50:43 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:50:44 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:50:45 PDT 2017
Sat May 20 18:50:46 PDT 2017
[...snip...]
```

(I used `cat fifo | another` for its parallism to the first `tail -f` version. 
 `cat` is unnecessary here.  We could have used `another <fifo`.)

Comment: Read my post. ;)

Comment: @varlogtim Read my answer.  I quoted the summary sentence from your post and did what the quote asked.  If you want something else, please be clear and precise.

Comment: Read stdout and write to stdin of a screen session, preferably with fifo files.

Comment: For some reason, as stated, piping the program output only contains the first couple of lines then stops.

Comment: Does your `application` flush its output?

Comment: @varlogtim (A) The above can be done inside a screen session the same as outside.  I added an example inside a screen session and using a fifo instead of a file.  (B) I cannot reproduce the issue with output stopping.  It continues for me.  Are you using my `application` and `another` or something different?

Comment: I can probably figure this out then update with the answer.